# Error lnk 1104 - cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, sdk, linker

before you mark this topic as duplicated let me explain.

Today at job I was upgrading from VS2010 to VS2013, before doing that I have been instaling sp1 on my computer. Unexpectedly when I opened new C project I got error lnk 1104 - cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'.

With qiuck search on the internet I have been realized that because I had VS2010, VS2013 cannot find the sdk file which inculdes the kernel32.lib. I have tried every solution on the internet and I cannot fix this. Here is a list of what I have already tried:

- Go to properties > linker > input > additional dependencies and add the sdk path (c:\program files(x86)\microsoft skds\ windows[curr
  sdk])
- Run on win64
- Rebot
- Reintall

How can I fix this? thank you.

Comment: Which edition of Visual Studio 2013 are you using? VS 2013 Express for Windows, VS 2013 Express for Windows Desktop, VS 2013 Community, something else?

Comment: VS sucks. This caused me a failure in a company's coding test recently. So VS sucks.